# How to get back project point cloud from rendered rgbd images by rgbd?

Tags: opengl, perspective

Given a sequence of RGB-D images rendered by blender and the camera parameters for the blender camera(Perspective Projection camera).

How can I back project the RGB images with depth map to a RGB point cloud?

TL,DR: How to back project (Perspective Projection camera) the RGB point cloud with RGBD sequence?

Thanks